# rabbitmq when to use basic reject over basic nack?

Tags: rabbitmq

Basic nack provides facility to return negative acknowledgement for one or multiple messages.

Basic reject has facility to return negative acknowledgement for only one message.

Do we have any use case where we definitely need basic reject?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With rabbitmq you can always `nack` over reject. Logically there is no explicit need to use `reject`, since `nack` can do anything `reject` can. As you said, both of these work for one message, but `nack` also for multiple.

Also `nack` is introduced by rabbitmq (so it's an extension), and is not part of amqp 0.9.1 specs.

Comment: *but reject also for multiple. OR nack also for multiple

Answer (score 20):

The answer by @cantSleepNow is correct, I would also like to add one more difference which is in their default behaviour.

By default, `nack` will put the message back in the queue for later handling. You can change the setting to not re-queue with `nack`.

With `reject`, by default, the message is not re-queued by RabbitMQ but will drop the message from the queue entirely.

Comment: Yeah this answer is a bit more appropriate, there is a good difference between the two (beyond sending it for one vs multiple messages). The [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#acknowledgement-modes) calls this out too

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to be true when consuming messages from rabbitmq management. Upon retrieving the message **Nack with requeue true** and **reject with requeue true** puts the message back into the queue